# The interval of convergence for two similar power series

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Let $\{a_{n}\}$ and $\{b_{n}\}$ be the sequence of positive real numbers with $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=1,$$
and let $R$ be the radius of convergence for a power series $\sum a_{n}x^{n}$.

If my attempted proof is correct, it seems that the radius of convergence for a power series $\sum b_{n}x^{n}$ is also $R$, where the main idea of my proof as follows:$$\frac{b_{n}}{b_{n+1}}=\frac{b_{n}}{a_{n}}\cdot\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}\cdot\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}.$$

Here is my question.

Can we say that the intervals of convergence for the two power series are also the same?

I'm not sure about the case for $x=-R$.

I would really appreciate it if you could give me some advice or any reference.

Thank you.

Comment: The intervals are of course the same. The behavior at the end points, not necessarily so.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Can you give me some examples?

Comment: Sure, but there is no point. With this particular problem, understanding an example is in no way easier than creating one yourself. Well, how about this: $1\over\sqrt n$ and ${1\over\sqrt n}+{(-1)^n\over n}$.